# adding MRLs to a playlist VLC

Tags: audio, vlc

I am having trouble making a playlist for MRL networks streams. Each time I open a new network stream it creates a new playlist and the previous stream is no where to be found (the history is overwritten with the most recently opened stream as well)
What steps do I have to take to create a MRL playlist? Do I need to store the playlist in a file somehow? I have been playing with the app for days and I cant find the answer here (https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Android/)  either

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling too to get a working playlist with VideoLAN on Android. Apparently the app didn't (and probably still does not) provide a way to have a playlist which doesn't vanish after shutting down the app I came up with a crude solution to create a file with a pls extension on the Android devide and have VLC load it. Still I had to do this on every launch of the application, but it worked. I describe details at http://vlc-playlist-android.blogspot.com/ and hope other could benefit from it. If VLC itself now provides a working playlist, please let me know in the comments there, or here.

Answer (score 1):

Input the MRL where VLC android asks in order to play the stream.  Once playing at the bottom of your android screen keep your finger pressed on the stream being played.  VLC player for android then goes to this screen where it shows the stream being played at the top of the screen and below it a list of your media files on your phone...  to the top right hand side tap the menu and there it gives you the option to save the playlist for the current stream you are listening to.   Krykie!!  it took me a bit to figure that out and absolutely no thanks to the help files on the official VLC site what so ever...  oh well.